# How to create a single running text using extjs4.2?

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations, extjs4.2, marquee

How to create running text like a marquee non standard HTML element in Extjs4.2 ?

This is my snippet code that I've done so far :

```js
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        Ext: '.'
    }
});

Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.XTemplate']);

Ext.onReady(function () {
    //Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', Ext.get('info').dom.innerHTML);
    Ext.define('v_label', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Label',
        xtype: 'runningText',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        constructor: function (config) {
            var me = this;
            var lbl = Ext.get('info').dom.innerHTML;

            this.data = {
                title: 'Title Sample',
                item: 'Item Sample'
            };
            this.tpl = lbl;
            // contentEl: 'info',
            this.height = 40;

            Ext.apply(me, config);
            me.callParent();
        }
    });

    Ext.create('v_label');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.1.1-gpl/resources/css/ext-all-debug.css" />
<div id="info">
    <marquee scrollamount='4' onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 4, 0);" onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);"><font size='5' color='red'><strong>{title} : {item}</strong></font> 
    </marquee>
</div>
```

I define it so I can create a dynamic label and store the data dynamically from `data:{}`.

You can see a running text, but it's double as you see. I've try to store the `marquee` tag into `tpl` but i get stuck because the `single quotes`, the `double quotes` and the `javascript to change the attribute marquee`.

**My question is :** How to make it a single running text ?

Or,

Maybe any another way to create running text in extjs4.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, change the lbl as the following.

```
// use backslash
var lbl = '<div id=\'info\'><marquee scrollamount=\'4\' onmouseout=\"this.setAttribute(\'scrollamount\', 4, 0);\" onmouseover=\"this.setAttribute(\'scrollamount\', 0, 0);\"><font size=\'5\' color=\'red\'><strong>{title} : {item}</strong></font></marquee></div>';
```

Comment: Very simple thought. For an answers like that I wait for a couple days.. +1 I like that :)